# Getting timed events

Tags: c#, timer

In my C# application, I need to call methods based on a timer. When I start the program, I want the timer to begin - and then call a method every 10 seconds.

Second - if I manually call the method prior to the 10 second span's expiration, I want the timer to reset - and wait 10 seconds from the execution (not fire when it would have). In other words - if the timer is at 6 seconds left, and I manually trigger - I want the timer to wait 10 seconds - not fire at 6.

1. What is the best way to create a timer like this?
2. Once I have the timer, how do I effectively control it's manual expiration?

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer

Comment: Could you post some code or pseudocode so we could help?

Comment: `System.Threading.Timer` is your way to go. Have a look at [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) for reference

Comment: Also please try to write in full sentences. That makes the question more readable. See also http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @Spotifixus I like [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) better since its properties (Interval, Autoreset, Enabled) and methods (Start, Stop) are a lot more sensible then the threading one

Answer (score 1):

The [System.Timer.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval.aspx) class suits all you needs.

> I want the timer to begin - and then call a method every 10 seconds.

This first part is easy you'll need to set the [interval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval.aspx) property to 10000, the [AutoReset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset.aspx) property to true and handle the [Elapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx) event.

> Second - if I manually call the method prior to the 10 second span's
>   expiration, I want the timer to reset - and wait 10 seconds from the
>   execution

Manually triggering is actually not so easy. The best way is to stop it, do whatever it was going to do in the elapsed event and then restart it.

However there is a big note on this. You'll need to make sure handling method is re-entrant because the timer gets executed on another thread than the manually triggered one. This is also a problem if your method could take 10 seconds to execute. Using a [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the easiest way.

To demonstrate the timer here's a small program that will manually fire when you hit enter and then wait two seconds to fire again.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 2000; // 2 seconds here
        timer.AutoReset = true; //Restart 


        Action<object, EventArgs> Elapsed = (object o, EventArgs e) => Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Elapsed);
        timer.Start();
        while (Console.ReadLine() != "quit")
        {
            timer.Stop();
            Elapsed.Invoke(new object(), EventArgs.Empty);
            timer.Start();

        }
    }
}
```